# TensorFlow CSV issues: Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the TensorFlow Python API to train a multilayer perceptron on a numeric dataset with 119 features.
Looking at the documentation, it seems more geared towards reading text files: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#file-formats

I get the following error:

InvalidArgumentError: Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside
     [[Node: DecodeCSV_15 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], field_delim=",", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReaderRead_11:1, DecodeCSV_15/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_15/record_defaults_1, DecodeCSV_15/record_defaults_2, DecodeCSV_15/record_defaults_3, DecodeCSV_15/record_defaults_4, DecodeCSV_15/record_defaults_5, DecodeCSV_15/record_defaults_6)]]

The relevant part of my code is:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["my-file.csv"],   num_epochs=1)

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 = tf.decode_csv(
value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.pack([col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7])
```

I'm also conscious that even if I get this working, I'll have to do the same for 119 columns, which is a bit impractical, and I'm wondering if it's overkill to use TensorFlow for this task in the first place.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Keras (http://keras.io/). It makes your life much easier when working with TensorFlow or Theano.

Comment: Can you share one line of your text file, so we can see why it might be failing? For what it's worth, I'd recommend encoding your 119 features per example as a feature group in the `tf.Example` protobuf-based format, because the parsing will be much more efficient (and less ambiguous) than CSV. Alternatively, you could use something like pandas to read your data in Python and feed the values into TensorFlow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Keras. I tried to read the CSV in as a pandas dataframe and then got another error: [34888 rows x 119 columns] has invalid type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a DataFrame into a Tensor or Operation.)           One line of the file: 
2,200,349,160,1,1,29

Comment: You can try calling the [`as_matrix()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) method on your DataFrame to get a numpy array, which can then be converted to a `Tensor`.

Comment: We meet the same problem, the feature value is like `["female","male","0"]`.